# AWS Cognito, AWS Amplify and custom scopes?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I have been trying to secure s3 buckets, ALBs and lambdas behind API gateway.

I use amplify so I can setup TOTP MFA. However, I don't get back custom scopes setup for that client id?

How do you setup custom scopes with amplify?

How does amplify login process not just give you back the custom scopes you specify but make you do a hosted UI oauth flows?

Is it possible to add the client id using the one of the lambda triggers for the oauth flows? (I ask since this would also solve my issues)

Answer (score 3):

Looks like this is a possible bug in the aws-amplify JS library https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/1370

"oauth scope settings for Amplify.configure not respected for Auth.signIn"

Basically as of right now, amplify will only return one scope not the full list of custom scopes. But maybe that will be fixed in the future in that bug ticket

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)